# Java Meaning of <String>

Tags: java, android, string

So I got a question, at the moment I am looking through java and found this declaration:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
```

What does  mean here, or in general.
I know that String is a datatype/class but I dont get these <> signs in which String is written in.

```
<String>
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Could you explain it easier, own words

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of has some excellent answers which explain what it means.